# Erlang append / concat one list to another list

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, tail-recursion

I know there are other ways to avoid using Accumulators and the built in `++` will append one list to another list. However, if I build my own tail recursive append function with an accumulator, is there any way of getting around using `lists:reverse()` on one of the lists like the snippet below? Thanks

```
joinWithAccumulator2(X,Y) ->
    joinWithAccumulator2(lists:reverse(X), [], Y).

joinWithAccumulator2( [], [], A ) ->
    A;

joinWithAccumulator2( [X | Xs], [], A ) ->
    joinWithAccumulator2( Xs, [], [ X |  A] ).
```

Comment: I don't know whether erlang supports difference lists.

Comment: The second argument in the arity 3 function is unused though. The accumulator ends up just being the second list.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Erlang, but I believe its lists are eager, not lazy -- so it needs to return a complete list, not a suspended function that can provide the next element on demand.  Also, functional-style lists (singly-linked/immutable) need to be extended stack-style -- by pushing elements on the front.  If both these conditions hold, you need to reverse your input list-of-lists one way or another -- either by using `reverse`, or by recursing down your input to start at the end (effectively using your stack as the reversal list)

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to build a list is to prepend elements using [H|T]. So the way you did it is efficient. If your purpose is to avoid to use the lib library, and in order to use the accumulator (see @juan.facorro comment) you can first reverse the first list in the accumulator, then prepend it to the second list:

```
joinWithAccumulator2(LX, LY) ->
    joinWithAccumulator2(LX, LY, []).

% first step reverse LX in LA
joinWithAccumulator2( [X | Xs], LY, LA ) ->
    joinWithAccumulator2( Xs, LY, [X |  LA] );
% second step, when LX is empty, prepend LA to LY (list accumulator2)
joinWithAccumulator2( [], LA2, [A | As] ) ->
    joinWithAccumulator2( [], [A | LA2], As );
% operation done
joinWithAccumulator2( [], A, [] ) ->
    A.
```